# custom tabbar tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tabbar

I am working on a project and I need tabbar tabs like this. I have tried using tabs->icon, text but it is smaller

#### The thing I want:

[image]

#### My Current Code:

```
  List<Tab> getTabs(int count, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
_tabs.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  categoriesmodel categ = snapshot.data[i];
  _tabs.add(
    getTab(
      categ.categories_name.toString(),
          categ.icon_of_category.toString(),
    ),
  );
}
return _tabs;
}


Tab getTab(String tabtitle, String imagepath) {
return Tab(
  icon: Image.network(
    imagepath,
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
  ),
  child: Text(
    tabtitle,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
  ),
);}
```

**Inside Appbar**

```
bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size(120, 120),
            child: Container(
              height: 120,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                indicatorColor: mainaccent,
                tabs: _tabs,
                controller: _tabController,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

**Result of my code**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This example can help you:**

```
 DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text('Flutter is Awesome' , style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          centerTitle: true,
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
            CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/image1.png')),
            CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/image2.png')),
            CircleAvatar(backgroundImage:  AssetImage('assets/image3.png')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(children: [
          Center(child: Text('First Tab')),
          Center(child: Text('Second Tab')),
          Center(child: Text('Third Tab'))
        ])
      ),
    );
```

**Output :**

[image]

> **Ideally ,** don't forget to wrap your Scaffold with `DefaultTabController`  .
> You can also use **TabBar** directly instead of AppBar like this : `appBar : TabBar()`. But make sure you have a `SafeArea`

Comment: tried wrapping it with DefaultTabController, But tabbar tabs height doesn't change a bit. I don't know what is the drill here, maybe the tabs height are fixed

Comment: Use toolbarHeight property to set the Toolbar Height . Example : toolbarHeight: 70.        I think it can help you .

Comment: tried this too but it only changes the height of appbar, not its tabbar

Comment: Use these property inside your  TabBar  .                                                                                                                                               
 indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label and
 isScrollable: true,